# Writing parquet file from transient EMR Spark cluster fails on S3 credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am creating a transient EMR Spark cluster programmatically, reading a vanilla S3 object, converting it to a Dataframe and writing a parquet file.

Running on a local cluster (with S3 credentials provided) everything works.

Spinning up a transient cluster and submitting the job fails on the write to S3 with the error: 
`AmazonS3Exception: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.`

But my job is able to read the vanilla object from S3, and it logs to S3 correctly.  Additionally I see that `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` is set as `EC2 instance profile`, and that `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole` has the proper S3 permissions, and that my bucket has a policy set for `EMR_EC2_DefaultRole`.

I get the the 'filesystem' that I am trying to write the parquet file to is special, but I cannot figure out what needs to be set for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

Arrrrgggghh!  Basically as soon as I had posted my question, the light bulb went off.

In my Spark job I had

```
val cred: AWSCredentials = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain().getCredentials
session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", cred.getAWSAccessKeyId)
session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", cred.getAWSSecretKey)
```

which were necessary when running locally in a test cluster, but clobbered the good values when running on EMR.  I changed  the block to

```
overrideCredentials.foreach(cred=>{
  session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", cred.getAWSAccessKeyId)
  session.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", cred.getAWSSecretKey)
})
```

and pushed the credential retrieval into my test harness (which is, of course, where it should have been all the time.)

Comment: If you are running in EC2 on the AWS code (not EMR), use the S3A connector, as it will use the EC2 IAM credential provider as the last one of the credential providers it uses by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in EC2 on the AWS code (not EMR), use the S3A connector, as it will use the EC2 IAM credential provider as the last one of the credential providers it uses by default.

The IAM credentials are short lived and include a session key: if you are copying them then you'll need to refresh at least every hour and set all three items: access key, session key and secret.

Like I said: s3a handles this, with the IAM credential provider triggering a new GET of the instance-info HTTP server whenever the previous key expires.